# Class resides in different directory than what the package specifies - how come?

Tags: java, package, javac

The following statements seem to disturbingly function:

```
robert@neghvar:~/tmp> cat org/foo/Bar.java 
public class Bar {

}

robert@neghvar:~/tmp> javac org/foo/Bar.java 
robert@neghvar:~/tmp> javap org.foo.Bar
Compiled from "Bar.java"
public class org.something.Bar extends java.lang.Object{
    public org.something.Bar();
}
```

Although the Bar class file is in the `org/foo` directory and declares the `org.something` package, the compiler does not complain. I was under the impression that java mandated a directory hierarchy which follows the package name. Was I mistaken? If so, what are the consequences of mixing up package names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's purely convention. The compiler will use the package names.

Having said that, it's not usually a good idea to break with this convention. It'll cause inconsistency (the classes generated will be in directories following the package) and some confusion!

Answer (score 3):

The **source directory structure** is not required to follow package naming (even though it almost always does by convention.)

I *think* the Sun/Oracle javac,javap,java,etc. tools (and all other Java implementations that I know of) are what mandate the subdirectory per package name component rule (along with the  default class loaders). I couldn't find anything authoritative, but it doesn't seem to be a requirement of the Java language specification:

- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html

Comment: Good answer, thanks for researching as well. It seems that no implementation requires it though - my example is done with Oracle's `javac` and `javap`.

Comment: By "requires", I meant that these tools are what generate the packages organization and require it at _runtime_. (The javac/javap programs don't require it of the source files.) The key point being the language (and JVM) specifications don't require subdirectory organization, but all the standard java tool implementations do.

Comment: They also require it at compile time for compiling dependent classes. If you compiled some other class that was dependent on Bar and Bar hadn't been compiled, the compilation would fail if Bar.java wasn't in the right place.